# How can I automatically upload files to a document library daily via SharePoint Designer?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

As stated, I'm using SharePoint designer and SharePoint online with Office 365. We want to automatically upload a log file to sharepoint every morning from a folder on a network location. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think the SharePoint Designer is good option in this scenario,

If you have an `up running on-prem server`, I suggest creating a console application that runs via a `task scheduler` as you prefer will be good and flexible option to achieve your requirements.

Below is the **CSOM** code to upload a file to a specific library in SharePoint Online:

```
string fileName = @"C:\logs.txt";
using (var context = new   ClientContext("https://yourdomain")) {
    var passWord = new SecureString();
    foreach (var c in "YourPassword") passWord.AppendChar(c);
    context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("YourUsername", passWord);
    var web = context.Web;
    var newFile = new FileCreationInformation {
        Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileName),
        Url = Path.GetFileName(fileName)
    };
    var docs = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Document Library Name");
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = docs.RootFolder.Files.Add(newFile);
    context.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Comment: What's the language for the code above? `C#`?

Comment: For the code above to work in C#, one may need to have certain packages installed:
`Install-Package System.Security.SecureString; Install-Package Microsoft.SharePoint.Client; Install-Package Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM;`.